# String Extract from PublicKey of Crypto.PubKey.Ed25519

Tags: haskell

This is my code, was trying in GHCI

```
import Crypto.PubKey.Ed25519
import Crypto.Error
import Data.ByteString.Char8

str :: String;str = "hellohellohellohelloǰello%$*/.õƲ"

getSecretKey seedString = throwCryptoError (secretKey (pack seedString))

getPublicKey secretKey = toPublic secretKey

sk = getSecretKey str

pk = getPublicKey sk
```

---

here pk's value is `PublicKey "\134M\130F\142\CAN\190\v,\228\190\232v\171\243]5\CAN\t\211\151\DC1]\188\t\206\233k\190\237\218>"`

I want to extract the string part `"\134M\130F\142\CAN\190\v,\228\190\232v\171\243]5\CAN\t\211\151\DC1]\188\t\206\233k\190\237\218>"`, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Data.ByteArray.convert  pk)::ByteString
```

This extracts ByteString (`"\134M\130F\142\CAN\190\v,\228\190\232v\171\243]5\CAN\t\211\151\DC1]\188\t\206\233k\190\237\218>"`) from `PublicKey "\134M\130F\142\CAN\190\v,\228\190\232v\171\243]5\CAN\t\211\151\DC1]\188\t\206\233k\190\237\218>"`